# Countdown timer that runs on server in php

Tags: javascript, php

How can I create a countdown timer in php that runs on a server. I have a countdown timer in javascript but it takes the current time from the user's system which i dont want. I want the timer should be same for all the user and time doesn't get affected if user changes the time on his system.

Comment: How about you send datetime variable from server and then use this date as base for your timer in JS?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's `date_default_timezone_set` function and set it to server's timezone or best will be `UTC`.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$curDT = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Pass this value in `JS` and use it for timer.

Comment: thanks man, it worked for me! but it is updating the timer only on page refresh. Please tell me how can this script update the time automatically?

Comment: Use `AJAX` to update it automatically i.e. without page refresh. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do this?

Comment: Will need code sample to give you proper solution. I need to understand your code and its flow. Can you post required HTML, JS and PHP code in your question?